# How do I add Ubercart product images in my Drupal module?

Tags: php, drupal, cck, ubercart, content-management

I'm writing a script that imports products from one of our suppliers, and I have almost everything importing correctly except product images.

From what I can tell, the product images are described in the `files` and `content_field_image_cache` tables. There don't seem to be any problems with the `files` table, so here is my code for inserting into `content_field_image_cache`.

```
$fileData->vid = $vid;
$fileData->nid = $nid;
$fileData->delta = 0;
$fileData->field_image_cache_fid = $fid;
$fileData->field_image_cache_list = 1;
drupal_write_record('content_field_image_cache', $fileData);
```

When I import products, the image file shows up in the correct directory, and a row is inserted into `files` with the correct path and an auto incremented `fid`. A row is also inserted into `content_field_image_cache` with the correct `vid`, `nid`, and `delta`, but every other field is set as *NULL*. Even when I set `$fileData->field_image_cache_fid = 1` or some other random integer, it still comes up *NULL*.

How do I insert this data? Or, if you know of an easier method in the API for this task, please post it.

**Edit:** `db_query("INSERT INTO {content_field_image_cache} VALUES (%d, %d, 0, %d, 1, NULL)", $vid, $nid, $fid);` doesn't even work! What the balls?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many ideas and failed attempts, I discovered that the entry is being added to the `content_field_image_cache` table before I have the chance to touch it. I have no idea what is inserting it; it's nothing in my code. Anyway, I found that using an `UPDATE` solved my problem.